# Api Post method not working in .net core azure production

Tags: azure, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am using .net core for expose API. When I call api from postman, some method not hitting, get 404 not found error message.

```
  [HttpPost]
    public async Task<bool> AddLogs([FromBody]List<LogModel> model)
    {
        var result = false;
        foreach (var item in model)
        {
            result = await _logService.Insert("Logs", item);
        }

        return result;
    }

   public class LogModel: TableEntity
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public bool IsBreak { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDateAndTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDateAndTime { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
  }
```

When I call the api 'AddLogs' , get not found error message.

But when try ,

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<bool> Post()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

It will return the true value.

But I noted that when I call in localhost 'AddLogs' api working fine. It will hit the api. But When I publish in azure, it shows me not found.

Comment: Joey's answer is a good place to start. It might be a routing problem. Another option is that when calling the Post you are submitting a body that is not recognized by the API model. i.e. if it's a List<object> make sure body is Json/app and it looks like [{...}]. Array brackets and object brackets in that order.

Comment: Yes, finally I found the issue, it's due to the DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

I test in my site and it works well.

The reason for this is that the deployment or default ASP.NET Core Web API template does not include a default document in the root directory of the web site.  For example, index.htm, defualt.aspx, default.htm are default documents and IIS will deliver them if there is no specific file provided when accessing the URL.

You could set `[HttpPost("AddLogs/")]` to specify the AddLogs action if you have several httppost method. Remember also add the following code in `Configure` method.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
});
```